# Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of Connect(Form())

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I'am using redux, react-router-redux and redux-form in my code. Code has a Provider, Connected router and Mini component. Mini component includes Switch and some components, which depends on route.

Index.js

```
...
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { ConnectedRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

import Reducers from './reducers'

const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: 'mini' })
const middlewareRouter = routerMiddleware(history)
const store = createStore(Reducers, applyMiddleware(middlewareRouter))

render(<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Mini/>
    </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Mini.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
...
import NavigationContainer from './containers/navigation'
import CategoryContainer from './containers/category'

class Mini extends Component {
    render () {
        return (<main>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/navigation" component={NavigationContainer}/>
                <Route path="/category" component={CategoryContainer}/>
                ...
            </Switch>
            <LoadContainer/>
            <div id="form"></div>
        </main>)
    }
}
```

All components in Switch section has a button. Clicking on the button can render a form.

```
...
import FormCreate from './formcreate'

class Topbar extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleClickCreate = this.handleClickCreate.bind(this)
    }

    handleClickCreate (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        render(<FormCreate/>, document.getElementById('form'))
    }
    ...
}
```

But when I click on button error appear `Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Form(FormCreate))"`

How can I fix the problem? Thanks in advance!

PS Reducers.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { routerReducer as reducerRouter } from 'react-router-redux'
import { reducer as reducerForm } from 'redux-form'

const Reducers = combineReducers({
    ...
    router: reducerRouter,
    form: reducerForm
})
```

PSS FormCreate.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

...

const FormCreate = (props) => {

    const { error, handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props

    return (
        ...
    )
}

export default reduxForm({

    form: 'create',
    validate

}) (FormCreate)
```

Comment: what is component `main` in Mini.js? React component should be capitalised. Also, what is the render in Topbar? is it a method from ReactDOM?

Comment: @D-reaper main is html tag. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are trying to render `FormCreate` create another app within html element `form` that does not have access to the redux store, resulting in the error that you see.

What I would do is set up a reducer that handle whether or not I should render `FormCreate` then render it in component in your app like in `LoadContainer`.

**Topbar.js**

```
class Topbar extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleClickCreate = this.handleClickCreate.bind(this)
    }

    handleClickCreate (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        // dispatch action to reducer to tell store to display FormCreate
    }
    ...
}
```

**LoadContainer.js**

```
class LoadContainer extends Component {

    // ... rest of code

    render() {
        // get shouldDisplayForm from redux store
        const { shouldDisplayForm } = this.props;

        return (
            //... rest of component
            { shouldDisplayForm && <FormCreate> }
        );
    } 
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to render FormCreate in html element 'form', you can put the store in a file so that you can require it in many files. Then render FormCreate with Provider like what you've done Index.js.

Comment: Thank you for answear! Your decision will be good, if the forms render into each of `<Switch>` components. But each of `<Switch>` components have there own forms, forms must render in `<LoadContainer/>` or you can replace `<LoadContainer>` by `<div id="load"></div>`.

Comment: I'm just using LoadContainer as an example. You can store the state of each form in the redux store and render the form in each of the components in `Switch`. The main issue is here is that you should not be rendering to the DOM where it does not have access to the redux store.

Comment: Ok, but I want to know, how to render form's of Switch components into container, which is outside of Switch.

Comment: I found a decision, but its not good. That is why I ask such question. You can see my decision in another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030410/how-to-pass-a-redux-store-into-dynamically-rendered-redux-form-component

Comment: by that i assume you want to render to a html element (e.g `<div id="form">`) without getting the error?

Comment: I update Mini.js code. Yes, I want to render redux-form into `<div id="form"></div>` without errors. As I understand, error appear because Provider store is not connected to the newly render components. And I want to understand how to clearly pass store into newly render component? Sorry, if my explanation is confusing.

Comment: You can put the store in a file so that you can require it in many files. Then render FormCreate with Provider like what you've done Index.js. I don't know if it will work though.

Comment: I will try it, so as I understand - I can use many <Provider> components in one application? Is it right?

Comment: Thank you for your patience :) I put the store in separate file, then wrap form component in Provider and pass store here. And it works!

Comment: Cool. In that case you can accept my answer then :)