# How to pass a redux store into dynamically rendered redux-form component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have a React Redux application, which is using redux-form. Form is render dynamically by event. While it render, I'am getting an error `Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Form(FormCreate))"`

To fix error, I explicitly pass a store into Form component, as bellow

```
render(<FormCreate store={store}/>, document.getElementById('form'))
```

But store also needed by redux-form custom render fiedls. For example

```
<Field store={store} component={renderField} type="text" name="text" label="Text"/>
```

Error was go away, but it seems to me bad approach :) That's why I ask how can I pass a redux store into rendered redux-form component more simply?

PS Can I wrap rendered form component into Provider, if Root element was already wrapped in Provider?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reduxForm decorator for your form which will fix this issue for you. In the example below, SimpleForm is a React component that consists of a form. This will make the data from your Field components to appear in the Redux state. Decorators are however only part of es7 but is available in Typescript.

```js
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'simple' // a unique identifier for this form
})(SimpleForm)
```

The jsfiddle below shows a full example of how to use the reduxForm decorator this.

https://jsfiddle.net/bmv437/75rh036o/

Comment: Ok, I used decorator as redux-form documentation says, but store is not pass into newly render form. I decide a problem by wrapping <FormCreate> with second `<Provider store={store}>`.

Comment: The reduxForm decorator will not give you the store as a prop to your component but it will rather make sure you don't need to provide the store to the component. It will make sure that your data from the fields will end up in the redux state.